# How can I fix Bitcode error when linking in Xcode 14

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am getting a build error "does not contain bitcode" on our build machine when linking. It builds on my MacBook running Xcode 13.3.1.

Any solution? Unity should not be requiring bitcode as it has been deprecated by Apple.

Unity 2021.3.11f1
Xcode 14.0.1

> ld: '/Users/teamviewer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cichdgwogxgtnhchbimudlupdljd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Pods_UnityFramework.framework/Pods_UnityFramework(Pods-UnityFramework-dummy.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/teamviewer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cichdgwogxgtnhchbimudlupdljd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Pods_UnityFramework.framework/Pods_UnityFramework' for architecture arm64

Comment: Since [Bitcode is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes) and will be removed, I'd just turn Bitcode off in your project.

Comment: @DarkDust And how to di it if in XCode 14 there is no such option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your project automatically disable bitcode, drop the following script into an `Editor` folder in your Unity project:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using System;
#if UNITY_IPHONE
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
#endif

public class MyPostProcessor : IPostprocessBuildWithReport
{
    private static Tuple<string, string>[] IosBuildValuesToSetInProject = {
        new Tuple<string, string>("ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO"),
    };

    int IOrderedCallback.callbackOrder => int.MaxValue;

    public void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildReport report) {
        BuildTarget target = report.summary.platform;
        string appPath = report.summary.outputPath;

        if (target != BuildTarget.iOS) {
            Debug.LogError("OnIosPostProcess - Called on non iOS build target!");
            return;
        }
        string pbxprojPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(appPath);
        if (File.Exists(pbxprojPath)) {
            PBXProject project = new PBXProject();
            project.ReadFromFile(pbxprojPath);
            foreach (var bv in IosBuildValuesToSetInProject)
            {
                project.SetBuildProperty(project.ProjectGuid(), bv.Item1, bv.Item2);
            }
            project.WriteToFile(pbxprojPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea turning off bitcode in the project solved this for me, thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).